# Classifying treatment levels as categorical or continuous

Tags: categorical-data, residuals, glmm, continuous-data

I am running a GLMM where one of the independent variables is treatment in terms of pesticide concentration, with four levels: 0ppb, 4.8ppb, 20ppb and 133ppb. I am unsure whether to class this variable as categorical or continuous. My instinct says continuous is best as it conserves the most information; however, I'm concerned that the fact that there are only four distinct values is affecting the model.

The main problem is the strange pattern of the plot of the residuals against the fitted values. This comes from a negative binomial GLMM with the variable treatment log-transformed (to deal with the unequal spacing between the treatment values).

[image]

Is this pattern likely to be due to classifying treatment as continuous? When I run the model using treatment as a nominal variable the residuals vs fitted plot shows no patterns.

I have also looked into using an ordinal variable with optimal scaling, but this seems unnecessary in my case as I know the values of each level *a priori*.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: If treatment can only take on the 4 values you mentioned--0ppb, 4.8ppb, 20ppb and 133ppb--you cannot enter this variable as continuous, because they are, by definition, not continuous.

Comment: The treatment could theoretically take on any value up to 1 billion, so could be continuous, but I have only sampled those four concentrations. If it's not possible to enter the variable as continuous, is there a way of incorporating the unequal distance between the levels in a categorical variable?

Comment: How many observations do you have in each of the 4 categories?  You can enter the concentrations as dummies and interpret the findings relative to the reference category.  You can enter the variable as continuous, but your statistical package doesn't know that you sampled only from those 4 concentrations.  If you enter it as continuous, the interpretation will be "for every unit increase in concentration..."  The problem is that you don't have any data on concentration values between 0 and 4.8, 4.8 and 20, 20 and 133.